# How should I refresh my screen under `perl -d -e 1`?

Tags: perl

People told me this is the perl interactive console.

But I found myself unable to refresh the screen, since `control` key doesn't work on this debug mode, press `h` key didn't show info about how to do that either.

So, how could I refresh the screen or move the current line to the top of terminal under `perl -d -e 1`?

Comment: OS-dependent, but `system("clear");` works here.  Sort of.  There's an empty line at the top of the screen from the debugger.

Comment: @tripleee, yes, that works, but it requires lot of work. `ctrl`+`L` is much faster, and `ctrl`+`P` is efficient to find the last command.

Comment: Installing [Readline support](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=838813) might improve your experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an alias within the debugger that does this for you:

```
= clear system 'clear'
```

after which you can just type `clear` to wipe the screen.

**Note** that on Windows systems this needs to be

```
= clear system 'cls'
```